# Sencha Touch 2 Native Packaging to Android device

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch-2, sencha-cmd

I have a problem creating an apps of sencha touch to the native packaging (for android platform).

I've tried many tutorials but none of it is successful. For android platform to create native packaging, which one is better? sencha CMD, phonegap or cordova?

I am using centos 6.5 or windows 7 to create this apps. I already develop an apps of the sencha touch but I want to package the apps to native apps.

Can someone help me with this? Am really at lost. Thank You.

These are among the link that I've followed:

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/guide/native_packaging

http://www.sencha.com/blog/getting-started-with-sencha-touch-2-build-a-weather-utility-app-part-3/

Comment: I think sbt native packager is wrong tag since it's plugin for building deb and rpm packages.

Comment: Oh sorry about that, I'm just a junior of the programming. Now I'm in internship of php and javascript developer company. Sorry for the mistake tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sencha CMD 4 is using cordova or phonegap integration for native packaging.

In a nutshell Apache Cordova and Adobe Phonegap are the same framework with the same source code. But PhoneGap project provides you a lot of cloud-based features (cloud build or hydration for example).

Sencha CMD is great tool to maintain you app.

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/guide/native_packaging is outdated.
Read this: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/guide/cordova

shell commands you'll need (for example):

```
$ sencha -sdk /path/to/sencha-touch-sdk generate app MyApp /path/to/myapp
$ cd /path/to/myapp
$ sencha cordova init
$ sencha cordova platform add android
$ sencha cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device
$ sencha cordova build android
```